# Get first child ID from an article with just a class name with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have my code like this. It is supposed to show like horizontal buttons with dates. When the user clicks on one of that buttons, the box expands itself showing the pictures in it.

I'm trying to get the first child ID of the article clicked with jquery to be able to show the gallery_items with the first child ID without the "_title" at the end. But I get undefined.

My html:

```
<section id="gallery">
    <article class="gallery_date">
        <div id="1389848400_title">16-01-2014</div>
        <div class="gallery_items" id="1389848400">
            <a href="content/uploads/261689_10150238069156283_4353481_n.jpg">261689_10150238069156283_4353481_n.jpg</a><br>
            <a href="content/uploads/IMG_4667.jpg">IMG_4667.jpg</a><br>
            <a href="content/uploads/millenium2.png">millenium2.png</a><br>
        </div>
    </article>
    <article class="gallery_date">
        <div id="1389762000_title">15-01-2014</div>
        <div class="gallery_items" id="1389762000">
            <a href="content/uploads/IMG_4661.jpg">IMG_4661.jpg</a><br>
        </div>
    </article>
    <article class="gallery_date">
        <div id="1389675600_title">14-01-2014</div>
        <div class="gallery_items" id="1389675600">
            <a href="content/uploads/bcn.png">bcn.png</a><br>
            <a href="content/uploads/logoenmedio.png">logoenmedio.png</a><br>       
        </div>
    </article>
</section>
```

My Jquery:

```
$().ready(function() {
    $(".gallery_date").click(function(event) {
        console.log($(".gallery_date:first-child").attr("id"));
    });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: `$(this).find(":first-child").attr("id").split('_').shift()` and use `$(document).ready(function() {...});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"I'm trying to get the first child ID of the article clicked  with jquery to be able to show the `gallery_items` with the first child ID without the `"_title"` at the end."*

Do this:

```
$(this).children().first().prop("id").split("_")[0];
```

---

Or without jQuery so it's not so verbose:

```
this.children[0].id.split("_")[0];
```

---

But if that's the only need for the ID, then you could just select the element with `.children()` by its class:

```
$(this).children(".gallery_items")
```

Answer (score 1):

**the first child ID without the "_title"**.

You can use `.replace()` to remove `'_title'` or you can use `.split()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".gallery_date").click(function(event) {
        var id = $(this).children().first().attr("id")
        console.log(id.replace('_title',''));

        console.log(id.split("_")[0]);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".gallery_date").click(function(event) {
        console.log($(this).find('.gallery_items:first-child').attr("id"));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".gallery_date").click(function(event) {
    console.log($(this).children().first().attr("id"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your html is structured the way it is, you can also just use the .next() method to get the gallery_items div, like this, so you don't have to worry about getting IDs and retrieving the DOM elements again:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".gallery_date").click(function() {
        $(this).next(".gallery_items").slideDown();
    });
});
```